# noexcept preservation using bind

Tags: c++, c++17, bind, noexcept

I have a problem with preservation of `noexcept` specifier in [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), using C++17.
In GCC and Clang is not preserved, but in MSVC it is. It seems that using `bind` with a function with `noexcept` specifier, the resulting object doesn't preserve it, considering always that it isn't `noexcept`.

Having a function like:

```
void f(int) noexcept;
```

And now creating a callable with `std::bind` on it:

```
auto g = std::bind(f,5);
```

It can be seen that `noexcept` behaviour is different between `f` and `g` when executing in GCC and Clang (using C++17 mode)

```
std::cout << noexcept(f(5)); //prints 1, ok, as expected
std::cout << noexcept(g()); //prints 0, WRONG!!
```

As mentioned at the beginning, **MSVC is the only with (in my opinion) consistent behaviour**. Reading the standard specification doesn't mention anything about that, so maybe this behaviour is not specified
So, is this a normal behaviour because the lack of specification in the standard or is a bug?

Is any way to force the "`noexcept`" specifier when using `bind`?

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `std::bind` if you are in C++17 mode. You can use a lambda instead.

Comment: I know this could be a solution in some cases, in fact is the way I have resolved it for some cases, but because the genericity of the code I'm writting, this can't be always achieved. Thanks

Comment: Do you need to exactly support uses of `std::bind`? or can you write a intermediate function and use that one rather than `std::bind`?

Comment: Hi Afshin. I can use (in fact I'm using it) lambda as a workaroung for some cases. The thing is that I need to know de exception specifier (via noexcept() or std::is_nothrowable_invocable) to take some decissions inside a templated library. But, I don't want to force the users to know about this fact, because any callable can be passed as argument to this library interface. But is clear now that this seems to be the normal behaviour for std::bind, so I will need to refactor the code as possible. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you can use C++20, then you can just use [`std::bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front), which not only has better performance than `std::bind`, but the `operator()` of the *perfect forwarding call wrapper* it returns is `noexcept` if the `std::invoke` expression it calls is `noexcept` (in other words, it preserves the exception specification of the underlying call operator), so the following `static_assert` can pass for all three compilers

```
#include <functional>

void f(int) noexcept;

auto g = std::bind_front(f,5);

static_assert(noexcept(f(5)));
static_assert(noexcept(g()));
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d3x7vTveb)

Comment: Thanks. It would be a solution I a could use C++20, but it's not possible right now, and this is the reason a specified that i'm using C++17 at the beginning. But thank you anyway